# How to deploy a bytecode-only contract without an ABI

Tags: contract-deployment, abi, hardhat, bytecode, deployed-bytecode

I see a contract's bytecode on chain that I want to re-deploy almost verbatim, but the issue is that there's no verification -- no ABI or source code. Can I still redeploy this contract to a hardhat instance to test and main chain somehow without the ABI? Can I get the ABI from a decompiler? I know how to parse and reproduce the inputdata of calls to it, so don't need to understand the exact details of the contract.

Ideally, looking for code that can do so. I'm guessing it should be generally possible, but I can't figure out how to get around the bytecode + ABI ethereum upload spec (I cannot find a function that takes just bytecode and sends it).

Comment: It depends how much you trust yourself on knowing the contract. I won't use a bytecode only contract for anything serious, just for testing.

Comment: You can take a look at the transaction that deployed the contract: this type of reverse engineering will probably allow you to deploy the same bytecode.

Comment: @eth I tried -- the transaction is just the exact same data as the contract.

Comment: Transaction's payload is different from the smart contract bytecode. The tx payload contains: code to deploy the smart contract, the bytecode, the parameters for the constructor. I answered below with an acutal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with Ethers v6 and Hardhat, in Typescript:

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

async function main() {
    const [wallet] = await ethers.getSigners();
    
    const bytecode = '0xdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef'
    
    const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory([], bytecode, wallet);
    const deployedContract = await contractFactory.deploy();
    const dep = await deployedContract.waitForDeployment();
    console.log(dep);
    console.log("Deployed to:", dep.target);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need ABI to deploy a smart contract, it is usually used by the abstraction layer of libraries to create dynamic objects that help developers with further calls, but it is not used in the deployment phase.

That said, you can copy and deploy an already deployed smart contract without any modification in 99% of the cases, but if there's *peculiar* business logic inside the constructor.

Here is an example where I *blindly* copied and pasted the payload from the original TX of a famous complex and fully functional smart contract. Can you guess what is it?

NodeJS prerequisites:

```
npm install web3 --save
npm install ethereumjs-tx  --save
```

Local geth with remix:

```
geth --http --http.corsdomain="https://remix.ethereum.org" --http.api web3,eth,debug,personal,net --vmdebug --dev console
```

File `deploy.js`:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

// CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR SENDER
let account = '0x000';

const rpcURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8545';
const web3 = new Web3(rpcURL);

// ABI IS NOT NEEDED
let abi = '[]'

let bytecode = '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';

let deploy_contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));

let payload = {
    data: bytecode
}

let parameter = {
    from: account,
    gas: web3.utils.toHex(8000000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('30', 'gwei'))
}

deploy_contract.deploy(payload).send(parameter, (err, transactionHash) => {
    console.log('Transaction Hash :', transactionHash);
}).on('confirmation', () => {}).then((newContractInstance) => {
    console.log('Deployed Contract Address : ', newContractInstance.options.address);
})
```

Deploy with:

```
node depoly.js
```

*Answer: CryptoKitties ;)*

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can. The ABI is not required to deploy any contract, you need it to verify it (not mandatory) and to interact with it in a simplified manner. For instance, you can deploy any ERC20 compliant contract to the blockchain, avoid to verify it, and still you will be able to interact with it using any ERC20 compliant call, generated whatsoever. Or, if you want, you can use locally on your side any ERC20 compliant ABI in order to generate the calls to it.

To generate a suitable ABI for any already deployed contract is a different kind of problem, very hard to face without a very deep knowledge about smart contract which you, apparently, do not have at the moment. Let me simply say that no decompiler able to give you the ABI needed to interact with a given already deployed contract do exist, neither it can exist, because the ABI is composed by the collection of all the function calls, each completed by the type of the parameters, each strongly sha256 hashed before being deployed to the blockchain. So, being definitively impossible to invert that hash, you will not able to have the original name and parameters type list.

You can try to guess some reasonable interface (I.e. ABI) for each function and make a test hashing it in order to compare with the call table in the deployed smart contract, but it is something complicated and you cannot be sure to find a solution in any general case.

Comment: Do you have some code that can do it? I agree it should be generally possible, but I can't figure out how to get around the bytecode + ABI ethereum upload spec (like I literally cannot find a function that takes just bytecode and sends it). I also don't appreciate the dig at my knowledge, I asked a question to receive help.

Comment: It sounds me like a deprecation of my help. I spent some time in trying to help you. Sorry for this. May be someone can help you better than me.